# Integration of one form /Line inegral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am given the form $\omega=xy^2dy-x^2ydx\;$ and $C \; $is the circle which is $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$.

Now I want to evaluate the integral $\int_C w =\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2(t)(2\sin^2(t)+3\sin(t)+1)dt=\frac{3}{2}\pi\;$ given the parametrization of $C\;$ $\alpha(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t)+1)$.
 However, using Greens theorem I get $2\pi\;$

With Green theorem I can transform the above integral to a double integral, so in my case I only have to evaluate the ingral $\; \int_D {x^2+y^2dxdy}\;$

I checked the integral using wolfram alpha. Can someone tell me what I did wrong ?

Comment: Recalculate. The value of $\int_D x^2+y^2\,dx\,dy$ is not $2\pi$.

Comment: @DanielFischer guess I used the wrong boundaries. How do I get proper boundaries for my integral ?

Comment: The easiest way to evaluate it would be (translated) polar coordinates, I think.

Comment: @DanielFischer I think I actually got It now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$C = \partial D$ is defined such that $x=\cos{t}$, $y=1+\sin{t}$ on $C$. In polar coordinates, this translates to $r=2 \sin{\theta}$ and we have

$$\iint_D dx \, dy \; (x^2+y^2) = \int_0^{\pi} d\theta \, \int_0^{2 \sin{\theta}} dr \, r^3 = 4 \int_0^{\pi} d\theta \, \sin^4{\theta} = \frac{3 \pi}{2}$$

On the other hand, the integral of the one-form is

$$\begin{align}\oint_{\partial D} \omega &= \int_0^{2 \pi} dt \, \left [\cos^2{t} (1+\sin{t})^2 + \cos^2{t} \sin{t} (1+\sin{t}) \right ]\\ &= \int_0^{2 \pi} dt \, \cos^2{t} + 3 \int_0^{2 \pi} dt \, \cos^2{t} \sin{t} + 2 \int_0^{2 \pi} dt \, \cos^2{t} \sin^2{t}\\ &= \pi +0+\left (2 \cdot \frac 14 \cdot \pi \right ) \\ &= \frac{3 \pi}{2} \end{align}$$